# Nested FPifeq : Extra \fi error

Tags: conditionals, fp

I want to have a command Unit with 1 parameter that return :

- nothing if the parameter is 1
- `-` if the parameter is -1
- the parameter in any other case

The goal is to show *x* and -*x* instead of 1*x* and -1*x* in my randomly generated exercices.

Here is the command I made :

```latex
\newcommand\Unit[1]{\FPifeq#1{1}{}\else\FPifeq#1{-1}{-}\else#1\fi\fi}
```

However, it generate the following error

```
Extra \fi
```

Minimal example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fp}


\begin{document}

\newcommand\Unit[1]{\FPifeq#1{1}{}\else\FPifeq#1{-1}{-}\else#1\fi\fi}

\Unit{2}x \Unit{1}x \Unit{-1}x


\end{document}
```

Comment: please put minimal examples inline not as an external link (this question will be archived forever, but that link will most likely break, or the document there will change)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro `\FPifeq` doesn't like to be nested in a conditional, because it is *not* a conditional. Its structure is basically

- do some comparisons that eventually help to decide whether to execute `\FP@testtrue` or `\FP@testfalse`, which make `\ifFP@test` equal to either `\iftrue` or `\iffalse`;
- set `\ifFPtest` equal to `\ifFP@test`;
- release `\ifFPtest` in the input stream.

However, TeX does not recognize `\FPifeq` as a conditional, so with your macro

```
\FPifeq#1{1}{}\else\FPifeq#1{-1}{-}\else#1\fi\fi
```

the following happens

- when `#1` is `1`, then `\ifFPtest` is `\iftrue`, and we end up with

  ```
  \iftrue{}\else\FPifeq#1{-1}{-}\else#1\fi\fi
  ```

  Now `{}` will be left in the input stream and the `\else` will remove everything up to the matching `\fi`. Oh, no! Another `\fi` remains!
- when `#1` is not `1`, then `\ifFPtest` is `\iffalse`, and we end up with

  ```
  \iffalse{}\else\FPifeq#1{-1}{-}\else#1\fi\fi
  ```

  Now everything up to `\else` is removed and we remain with

  ```
  \FPifeq#1{-1}{-}\else#1\fi\fi
  ```

  but TeX remembers it has removed an `\else`. Then everything will work well, because at the end of the job of `\FPifeq` either `\iftrue` or `\iffalse` will result. The trailing `\fi` corresponds to the `\else` removed in advance, so it doesn't harm.

There are a few glitches in your code: it should be `{#1}` throughout, otherwise a value such as `12` would take `1` as the first argument to `\FPifeq` and `2` as the second argument.

You *could* fix the nesting problem by doing

```latex
\newcommand{\FPeq}{TT\fi\FPifeq}
\newcommand\Unit[1]{%
  \if\FPeq{#1}{1}%
    % do nothing
  \else
    \if\FPeq{#1}{-1}%
      -%
    \else
      #1%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

This is an old trick that uses `\if` to make the problem above vanish; if `\if` is expanded, it sees `TT\fi`, which results in a true test and `\FPifeq` will be executed; if it is in skipped text, it will correctly match a corresponding `\else` or `\fi`.

However, the usage of `\FPifeq` has bad consequences on the final output. Let's see an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\FPeq}{TT\fi\FPifeq}
\newcommand\Unit[1]{%
  \if\FPeq{#1}{1}%
    % do nothing
  \else
    \if\FPeq{#1}{-1}%
      -%
    \else
      #1%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

$\Unit{2}x$ $\Unit{1}x$ $\Unit{-1}x$

$2x$ $x$ $-x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you see the problem? The working of `\FPifeq` creates an empty math atom, so the minus sign is treated as a binary operator rather than a unary, if leading the polynomial.

The problem does not show with Phelype Oleinik's code using `expl3`.

Comment: Thanks for this deep explaination. Also thanks about using {#1} instead of #1. I made this error multiple times in my document and I would never have understand why my code suddently stopped working the day I would trigger the error.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `fp` for that. TeX can do integer comparison with `\ifnum`. This:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Unit[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=1
    % nothing
  \else
    \ifnum#1=-1
      -%
    \else
      #1%
    \fi
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\Unit{2}x \Unit{1}x \Unit{-1}x
\end{document}
```

produces `2x x -x`.

---

If you want to use `fp`, then you need to hide the second test in another macro. Apparently `fp` doesn't like nested conditionals:

```latex
\newcommand\Unit[1]{%
  \FPifeq{#1}{1}%
    % nothing
  \else
    \UnitInner{#1}%
  \fi}
\newcommand\UnitInner[1]{%
  \FPifeq{#1}{-1}%
    -%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi}
```

However, I recommend you use `expl3` and it's own FPU. It's much more flexible and allows you to easily compose nested conditionals:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \Unit { m }
  {
    \fp_compare:nF { #1 == 1 }
      {
        \fp_compare:nTF { #1 == -1 }
          { - }
          { #1 }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\Unit{2}x \Unit{1}x \Unit{-1}x
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ty. By curiosity, do you know why I got this error and how to fix it ? I might need to do non integer comparison one day.

Comment: @Matheod I complemented the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification